# On average, how many times must a 6-sided die be rolled until the sequence 65 appears (i.e., a 6 followed by a 5)?

Tags: probability, dice

On average, how many times must a 6-sided die be rolled until the sequence 65 appears (i.e., a 6 followed by a 5)?

i tried it using  this way.
let say there are E rolls until we get 65.
when we roll die first time,there is 1/6 probability that we get 6 and 5/6 probability of not getting 6.in case of 5/6, we have to start all over again,so now our number of steps are (E+1).
if we get 6 in first roll , then there are 3 cases.
(a) we roll a 5, (b), we roll a 6, or (c) we start all over again.
in (a) we get our 65 so here our additional number of steps are 1 and probability is 1/6.
in (b) we got 6 so will roll again to get 5 . so our additional number of steps now are (E-1)
in (c) we have to start all over again so our additional number of steps are (E+2)

so my equation is 
E = (5/6)(E+1)+(1/6)(1+(1/6)(1)+(1/6)(E-1)+(4/6)(E+1))

by solving this , i got 40 but ans given ans is 30. where did i wrong?please help.
thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know anything about expectation that might seem like it could be relevant?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.

Comment: In this simple case, due to the independence of sequences, it is simply one over the probability, so the answer is $36$.

Comment: The probability of rolling a $1,2,3,4,5,$ or $6$ is $\frac{1}{6}$. Therefore, the probability of rolling a $6$ followed by a $5$ is $\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{36}$ as they are independent of each other.

Comment: hi @Arthur,i have edited my question now ,please have a look.

Comment: hi @lulu ,i have eedited my question now please have a look.

Comment: hi @DonThousand , it's not 36.

Comment: I have posted something below.  The answer is indeed $36$, but I have given an argument for that value along the lines you started.

Comment: hi @lulu thank you for your efforts.

Comment: @DonThousand - what do you mean by "independence of sequences"?  The sequence $65$ appearing in the 1st & 2nd roll is not independent of the sequence $65$ appearing in the 2nd & 3rd roll (because they are exclusive).  So you must mean something else...?

Comment: @antkam I mean that since 65 has no repeating elements, once a sequence is broken, it is completely broken. As such, each instance of 65 is independent.

Comment: @DonThousand - you mean they cannot overlap?  but how does that (directly) imply the expectation is $36$?  if it should be obvious, i'm missing something.  or is this a non-obvious but proven theorem?  and does it generalize to e.g. sequences of $123$ or what about $1212$ (which can overlap)?  honestly, even if i feel the answer is $1/prob$, i would not know if i should guess $36$ or $37$ i.e. do i need $36$ "start" chances (for $37$ total rolls)?  :)

Answer (score 1):

To complete the calculation along the lines you started:

Let $E$ be the answer.  Let $E_6$ be the expected number of turns it takes, given that the last roll was a $6$.

Then we get $$E=\frac 16\times (E_6+1)+\frac 56\times (E+1)\implies E = E_6+6$$  and $$E_6=\frac 16\times 1+\frac 16 \times (E_6+1)+\frac 46\times (E+1)\implies 5E_6=4E+6$$

This system is easily solved and yields $E=36$.  (Note:  it also yields $E_6=30$ which, possibly?, is the source of the error in the "official" answer).

Comment: you are rigth. there was some confusion in ans . it is 36 actually. and yeah, E6 =30 also. thanks man!